# suppress warnings in rpy2

Tags: python, r, warnings, rpy2

When I import R in python, using rpy2, how do I suppress warnings?

It appears that in R you have to do just the following

```
options(warn=-1)
```

...but I'm not familiar with R. How do I do this in python?

Comment: Does these warnings follow from importing R packages at start, or are they issued during a regular session (e.g., for some R expressions)?

Comment: the latter, they are generated by some functions I'm calling.

Comment: `suppressWarnings()` might be an option then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much gave the answer yourself. You can call the `options(warn=-1)` function from Python by using RPy:

```
rpy.r['options'](warn=-1)
```

For RPy2 it should be something like this (haven't tried this):

```
rpy2.robjects.r['options'](warn=-1)
```

Just put it at the beginning of your Python script (after the module imports) and all warnings should be suppressed.

Comment: Seems not to work for rpy2. Obviously one can supprese brutally via:
`import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")`, which is not elegant at all, since it affects not only the rpy2 warnings

Answer (score 20):

The warning system in [rpy2](http://rpy2.bitbucket.org/) uses Python's [`warnings`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/warnings.html#module-warnings) module. As a consequence, you can switch off warnings using that package's [`filterwarnings()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings) function. As already pointed out in a comment to another answer here this could be dangerous as not only R-related warnings are affected.

However, rpy2 comes with its own warning class, `RRuntimeWarning`. Therefore, you can switch off only this type of warning by

```
import warnings
from rpy2.rinterface import RRuntimeWarning
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=RRuntimeWarning)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it is a solution to "suppress warnings in R". The accepted solution DOES NOT WORK.

Answer (score 5):

Beginning with 3.0 version, rpy2 does not use Python's `warnings` module [anymore](https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/issues/543). It now relies on `logging` instead. The new solution would be:

```
from rpy2.rinterface_lib.callbacks import logger as rpy2_logger
import logging
rpy2_logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)   # will display errors, but not warnings
```

If you want to filter specific warnings only, use:

```
rpy2_logger.addFilter(lambda record: 'notch went outside hinges' not in record.msg)
```

See [`LogRecord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-objects) class specification for available fields for advanced filtering.